# How to install DBD::Sybase in linux server

Tags: perl, module, sybase, dbd

I am not able to install DBD::Sybase module using *Makefile.PL* in linux. It's showing error

[Please set the SYBASE in CONFIG, or set the $SYBASE environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0tBb.png)

I am not able to identify which path need to set for SYBASE env variable as I set something it's shows there are no sybase library found.

[Error can't locate dbd:sybase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee8TS.png)

Comment: There is a file `CONFIG` in the same folder as `Makefile.PL`. What is the value of `SYBASE` in that file?

Comment: It's much better to include error messages and output as text.

Answer (score 0):

From the [DBD::Sybase documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Sybase):

> The OpenClient library uses the environment variable SYBASE to find the location of the interfaces file, as well as other files that it needs (such as locale files). The SYBASE environment is the path to the Sybase installation (eg '/usr/local/sybase'). If you need to set it in your scripts, then you must set it in a BEGIN{} block:

Comment: I used freetds driver to use sybase:dbd module but not able to make connection with sybase db.